# Saving city to User Model in Rails using Geocoder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, rails-geocoder

I've currently got my code working so that the Geocoder takes the user's IP address and saves the physical (along with a hard-coded IP address for development):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    geocoded_by :ip_address
    after_validation :geocode

    reverse_geocoded_by :latitude, :longitude
    after_validation :reverse_geocode

    def self.remote_ip
        if $request.remote_ip == '127.0.0.1'
          '111.11.333.666'
        else
          $request.remote_ip
        end
    end  

  user.ip_address = remote_ip
  user.location = user.address
```

Now I'm trying to get the city from the address. Looking at the docs, it provides this:

```
reverse_geocoded_by :latitude, :longitude do |obj,results|
    if geo = results.first
      obj.city    = geo.city
      obj.zipcode = geo.postal_code
      obj.country = geo.country_code
    end
 end
after_validation :reverse_geocode
```

This keeps giving me an "undefined method `city=' for User:" error.

Looking at this question asked previously on stackoverflow, [Rails Geocoder "undefined method error"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7865281/rails-geocoder-undefined-method-error) and [Can Ruby Geocoder return just the street name on reverse_geocode calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15489402/can-ruby-geocoder-return-just-the-street-name-on-reverse-geocode-calls), it says that I have to pass the model name instead of "obj" in the block above. How do I do that? I tried user,results but that didn't work.

Comment: Does your `User` model even have a `city` field?

Comment: No, do I need to add that as a migration, i.e. rails g migration AddCityToUsers city:string? I just want user.location to be the city.

Comment: OK, that seemed to do it.

Answer (score 0):

As Cody pointed out, I needed to add the city and country fields to my User model via migrations first.

```
 rails g migration AddCityToUsers city:string
 rails g migration AddCountryToUsers country:string
```

Final code:

```
reverse_geocoded_by :latitude, :longitude do |obj,results|
if geo = results.first
  obj.city    = geo.city
  obj.country    = geo.country
end
end
after_validation :reverse_geocode

user.location = user.city + ", " + user.country
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just:

```
reverse_geocoded_by :latitude, :longitude do |obj,results|
  if geo = results.first
    obj.city = geo.city
    obj.country = geo.country
    # make a combined field with both city/country
    obj.location = geo.city + ", " + geo.country
  end
end
after_validation :reverse_geocode
```

Comment: That works, but in my case location can be one of 2 things, it goes for their location of Facebook first before looking it up by IP address.